# Fewer rows written than expected with SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

When I am performing an insert operation for more than 1,00,215 rows, then it writes only 1,00,105 rows.

Is there problem of the buffer or cache memory? If this the problem then how to increase the size of the memory?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.csvreader.CsvReader;

public class CSVStoreData 
{
    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement smt = null;

    public void insertData(String path) 
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/D:\\DB\\Mediation.db");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            smt = con.createStatement();
            CsvReader filereader = new CsvReader(path,',');
            filereader.readHeaders();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(filereader.readRecord())
            { 
                String query="insert into CDRData values('"+filereader.get(0)+"','"+filereader.get(1)+"','"+filereader.get(2)+"','"+filereader.get(3)+"','"+filereader.get(4)+"','"+filereader.get(5)+"','"+filereader.get(6)+"','"+filereader.get(7)+"','"+filereader.get(8)+"','"+filereader.get(9)+"','"+filereader.get(10)+"','"+filereader.get(11)+"','"+filereader.get(12)+"','"+filereader.get(13)+"','"+filereader.get(14)+"','"+filereader.get(15)+"','"+filereader.get(16)+"','"+filereader.get(17)+"','"+filereader.get(18)+"','"+filereader.get(19)+"','"+filereader.get(20)+"','"+filereader.get(21)+"','"+filereader.get(22)+"')";
                //System.out.println(filereader.get(0)+","+filereader.get(1)+","+filereader.get(2)+","+filereader.get(3)+","+filereader.get(4)+","+filereader.get(5)+","+filereader.get(6)+","+filereader.get(7)+","+filereader.get(8)+","+filereader.get(9)+","+filereader.get(10)+","+filereader.get(11)+","+filereader.get(12)+","+filereader.get(13)+","+filereader.get(14)+","+filereader.get(15)+","+filereader.get(16)+","+filereader.get(17)+","+filereader.get(18)+","+filereader.get(19)+","+filereader.get(20)+","+filereader.get(21)+","+filereader.get(22));
                smt.executeUpdate(query);
                // System.out.println("\n");
            }
            System.out.println("Record Inserted");
            long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("The time taken by insert query : "+(finishTime-startTime)+ " ms");
            con.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error ---- "+e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVStoreData csvdata = new CSVStoreData();
        csvdata.insertData("D:\\CDRfile\\110527_160001.cdr");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the error ?

Comment: not generate error but it write record up to 1,00,105 only where other record go

Comment: You seem to be using SQLite, not BerkeleyDB.

Comment: Add a counter to your `while` loop to count how many times you successfully insert a row, then afterward compare it to both the number of rows in your target table and the number of rows in your input CSV file. That will at least help rule out any manual counting discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

You might be exceeding the maximum size for an SQLite Database.  Check out http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html (specifically, the last two paragraphs).  While you certainly aren't exceeding the maximum number of rows in a table, depending on what your max page count and page size are set to, you could be exceeding your maximum database size.

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count and http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size may also be useful to look at.

Mind checking those values and telling us what you get?